# How do I set environment variables in WAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter, wamp

I am trying to get an environment variable to show up in `$_ENV` in my codeigniter app. How do i do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set an environment variable in a few different ways. Some (not all?) are:

- put them in .htaccess files
- specify on the command line
- specify them in your Apache config file like this:

Apache config:

```
SetEnv env_var_name env_var_value
```

Comment: How do you set them through the command line? I've set one in git bash, can see it's there, but WAMP doesn't seem to know it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that when using [putenv()](http://php.net/putenv) the value will not be available in $_ENV, and you have to use getenv() to obtain the value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you need to accomplish you probably need to look at using [putenv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php) or if you want to change an apache environment variable, [apache_setenv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they show up in `$_SERVER`?